# How to use one single js function for multiple form elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

Here based on user entry number of forms will be created in a single HTML file. Here

```js
function jsfunction() {  
  var number1 = document.getElementById("number").value; 
  var number = parseInt(number1); 
  number += number;
  document.getElementById("result").value = number; 
}
```

```html
<body>

<?php 
  // this value is dynamically generated by refering database. Each time it varies.
  $count=2; 
?>

<input type="text" value="<?php echo $count; ?>" id="countt">

<?php
  for($i=0; $i<$count ; $i++ ) { 
?>

<form>  
  Enter No: <input type="text" id="number" name="number" onblur="jsfunction()"/><br/>  
  Value: <input type="text" id="result"/> 
</form>

<?php
  }
?>  

</body>
```

In each form I am using `onclick="jsfunction()"` for one element. 
Problem is this `jsfunction` is only working for 1st form. I need this same `jsfunction` to be performed on all the form elements individually.

Since the real code is huge I am sharing small scenario of same. Please look into the code and help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can dynamically assign unique ids to your forms like this. Then passing the parameter with the unique id number to a JS function will help to select the forms.

```js
function jsfunction(id) {  
  var number1 = document.getElementById("number_" + id).value; 
  var number = parseInt(number1); 
  number += number;
  document.getElementById("result_" + id").value = number; 
}
```

```html
<body>

<?php 
  // this value is dynamically generated by refering database. Each time it varies.
  $count=2; 
?>

<input type="text" value="<?php echo $count; ?>" id="countt">

<?php
  for( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ) { 
?>

<form>  
  Enter No: <input type="text" id="number_<?php echo $i; ?>" name="number" onblur="jsfunction(<?php echo $i; ?>)"/><br/>  
  Value: <input type="text" id="result_<?php echo $i; ?>"/> 
</form>

<?php
  }
?>  

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are using the same `id="number"` for each form.
Try with a unique id and pass it to the function:

```
jsfunction(the_id)
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem. You still will need to find the form the clicked control is part of to then find the result input with the unique id. Which Id do you want to pass? Both, or just one? Your answer is good advise without application and in fact, even while duplicate identifiers are bad practice you can solve this with duplicate identifiers by simply iterating through the DOM to find the clicked elements's parent and then using `querySelector` on that parent form  to find the sibling of the clicked element. Though `unbirth`'s answer is much more appropriate and clear.